# Updating MySQL database with MD5 value

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, md5

Having searched thoroughly through my code, the only reason that I could determine for this error is that the technique I am using for converting the string to MD5 is invalid. However I cannot find another way to do so.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$repassword = $_POST['repassword'];
if( $password=$repassword ) {
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    if( $con == true ) {
        mysql_select_db("movedb", $con);
        //$newpassword = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
        $query = "UPDATE user SET password=MD5('$password') WHERE username='$username'";
        // $query = "UPDATE user SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $con);

        if( $result == true ) { 
            echo "Successfully saved your message";
        } else {
            echo mysql_error();
        }   

        mysql_close($con);
    } else {
            echo "Cannot connect to the database";
    }

} else {
    echo "Passwords do not match!";
}
```

Any ideas on how to update this MD5 value from PHP

Comment: and fix that IF, you are assigning to it, you are not comparing

Comment: there is no error message obtained

Comment: @Yoosuf, if there is no error then you need to tell us what you are expecting from your code and what it is and is not delivering.

Comment: I am expecting the password to get updated in the database after getting converted to the Hash value. However the SQL does not seem to give any results even in PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Don't use normal hashfunctions such as md5 for password hashing. Use bcrypt or similar constructs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$password = md5($password);
$query = "UPDATE user SET password='".$password."' WHERE username='".$username."'";
```

Use PHP supported md5 hash.

Comment: no it does not get updated, and there is no error message displayed either

Comment: Then echo $query and put it into phpmyadmin and check whether there is such entry where username = $username.

Comment: Surprisingly, PHP MyAdmin says 0 rows affected!
UPDATE user SET password='202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70' WHERE username='admin '

Comment: You have username='admin ' << space after admin.

Comment: The SQL script worked when I entered it into the MySQL console. However when I try to login again from PHP it only accepts the Old Password!

Comment: I suppose you're praying that `$username` doesn't contain `'` aren't you? What is with the PHP community where this sort of casual recklessness is considered normal?

Answer (score 1):

To check the password:

`SELECT * FROM 'user' WHERE username='bob.jhonny' AND pass=MD5('oldPassword');`

To update:

`UPDATE 'dlp_contatcs'.'user' SET 'Pass'=MD5('NewPassword') WHERE 'Username'='bob.jhonny';`

Comment: MD5(NewPassword) as in from my previously converted one

Answer (score 1):

An issue that can cause problems is that MySQL and PHP use different default salts when they encrypt.  This means that the resulting strings will be different.  So you have to use either PHP *or* MySQL to encrypt and *not* a mixture of the 2.

Secondly, MD5 has been superceded by other better encryption algorithms.  You might consider using one of those for improved security.  Check out PHP's [`crypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

> **Warning:**
>
> Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?
>
> Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should give some details about deciding which API to use. For PDO, here is a [good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

You can calculate the `md5()` hash with PHP and store it into a variable, then put that variable into the database. Just make sure you do the same conversion (`md5` in the PHP code body) when checking against the database.

You should fix the line `if( $password=$repassword )`. You need either two or three `=` signs to make the `if` check against something. The proper line would be `if( $password === $repassword )`.

```
// ...
$newpassword = md5($_POST['password']);
$result = mysql_query('UPDATE user SET password="' .mysql_real_escape_string($newpassword). '" WHERE username = "' .mysql_real_escape_string($username). '"', $con);

if ( $result === TRUE )
{
    echo "Successfully saved your message.";
// ...
```

Comment: Yes I shall check out the latest version of PHP coding as well. Anyhow the code fragment you gave is also not working! There is no error message displayed and it does not get updated in the databae

Comment: @Yoosuf Please check whether the connection is successful, `user` table exists and that the `username` (in whose row you are wanting to update the `password`) exists too.

Comment: Yes the user table exists and so those the column username and the record admin.

Comment: @Yoosuf Using an external tool (like phpMyAdmin or `mysql` in command line) to execute a query succeeds in modifying the row?

Comment: not it doesnt make a difference it still says 0 rows affected

Comment: @Yoosuf Then there is something wrong with your database. Recreate the table and the data inside, and check for special characters (including whitespaces) in the fields. You might have added a space where it is not needed because this code **is** working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14346/discussion-between-yoosuf-and-whisperity)